# How to get body content from request in intercept method using express-http-proxy?

Tags: node.js, express

Wow to get a POST body content from a request. I need to log full requests in my app.

Here is my setup:

```
var express = require('express'),
    proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var app = express();
app.use('/test', proxy('google.com', {
    intercept: (rsp, data, req, res, callback) => {
        // Log request body here
        handle(rsp, data, req, res);
        callback(null, data);
    },
}));
```

Comment: What about `req.body`?

Comment: @stdob-- There is no such var.